# How can I import the whole sheet to another Google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, worksheet-function

I have a sheet (sheet1A) in Google spreadsheet A, and another spreadsheet - spreadsheet B

Now I want to have another sheet on B - called sheet1B - that's totally the same as sheet1A, with data get updated from 1A.

Because sheet 1A is under other person's control, I just want to have another place to take control of the data I get from A.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with importRange
use

```
=IMPORTRANGE("sheet id"; "range") function.
```

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=nl